# C#, Linq2SQL - tricks to fetch a ViewModel object with relation data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, mvvm

I don't know Linq2Sql so well yet and I was wondering if there is a trick for this probably common MVVM scenario. I have Linq2Sql data context containing Domain models, but I am fetching data for my customized ViewModel object from it.

```
var query = from ord in ctx.Table_Orders
        select new OrderViewModel()
        {
            OrderId = ord.OrderId,
            OrderSum = ord.OrderSum,
            OrderCurrencyId = ord.OrderCurrencyId,
            OrderCurrencyView = ord.Currency.CurrencyText
        };
```

So i want my ViewModel to inculde both CurrencyId from domain object and the CurrencyText from related table to show it nicely in the View.

This code works great. It generates one DB call with join to fetch the CurrencyText. But the model is **simplified**, real one has many more fields. I want to make the code **reusable** because I have many different queries, that returns the same ViewModel. Now every minor change to OrderViewModel requires lots of maintainance.

So I moved the code to OrderViewModel itself as a constructor.

```
public OrderViewModel(Table_Order ord)
{
    OrderId = ord.OrderId,
    OrderSum = ord.OrderSum,
    OrderCurrencyId = ord.OrderCurrencyId,
    OrderCurrencyView = ord.Currency.CurrencyText
}
```

And call it like this.

```
var query = from ord in ctx.Table_Orders
        select new OrderViewModel(ord);
```

**The Problem**: The join is gone DB query is no more optimised. Now I get 1+N calls to database to fetch CurrencyText for every line.

Any comments are welcome. Maybe I have missed different great approach.

This is how *far* i could get on my own, to get the code **reusability**. I created a function that does the job and has multiple parameters. Then I need to explicitly pass it everything that has **crossed** the line of entity.

```
var query = ctx.Table_Orders.Select(m =>
       newOrderViewModel(m, m.Currency.CurrencyText));
```

The DB call is again optimized. But it still does not feel like I am there yet! What tricks do You know for this case?

---

**EDIT : The final solution** 
Thanks to a hint by @Muhammad Adeel Zahid I arrived at this solution.
I created an extension for IQueryable

```
public static class Mappers
{
    public static IEnumerable<OrderViewModel> OrderViewModels(this IQueryable<Table_Order> q)
    {
        return from ord in q
                select new OrderViewModel()
                {
                    OrderId = ord.OrderId,
                    OrderSum = ord.OrderSum,
                    OrderCurrencyId = ord.OrderCurrencyId,
                    OrderCurrencyView = ord.Currency.CurrencyText
                };
    }
}
```

Now i can do this to get all list

```
var orders = ctx.Table_Order.OrderViewModels().ToList();
```

or this to get a single item, or anything in between with Where(x => ..)

```
var order = ctx.Table_Order
   .Where(x => x.OrderId == id).OrderViewModels().SingleOrDefault();
```

And that completely solves this question. The SQL generated is perfect and the code to translate objects is reusable. Approach like this should work with both LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities. (Not tested with the latter) Thank You again @Muhammad Adeel Zahid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we query the database, we mostly require either enumeration of objects (more than one records in db) or we want a single entity (one record in db). you can write your mapping code in method that returns enumeration for whole table like

```
public IEnumerable<OrderViewModel> GetAllOrders()
{
    return from ord in ctx.Table_Orders
        select new OrderViewModel()
        {
            OrderId = ord.OrderId,
            OrderSum = ord.OrderSum,
            OrderCurrencyId = ord.OrderCurrencyId,
            OrderCurrencyView = ord.Currency.CurrencyText
        };

}
```

Now you may want to filter these records and return another enumeration for example on currencyID

```
public IEnumerable<OrderViewModel> GetOrdersByCurrency(int CurrencyID)
{
      return GetAllOrders().Where(x=>x.CurrencyId == CurrencyID);
}
```

Now you may also want to find single record out of all these view models

```
public OrderViewModel GetOrder(int OrderID)
{
      return GetAllOrders().SingleOrDefault(x=>x.OrderId == OrderID);
}
```

The beauty of IEnumerable is that it keeps adding conditions to query and does not execute it until it is needed. so your whole table will not be loaded unless you really want it and you have kept your code in single place. Now if there are any changes in ViewModel Mapping or in query itself, it has to be done in GetAllOrders() method, rest of code will stay unchanged

Comment: Thanks, this is a great idea, however I just tested it and it does not work so beautifully for me. Look, in the last example, GetAllOrders().SingleOrDefault(..) still gets all Order data to be loaded. That is because x=>x.OrderId is actually a field of ViewModel OrderViewModel.OrderId not underlaying Table_Orders.OrderId model. In the process of querying Viewmodel, it loads all Model rows.
However, i am still testing on variations on this idea, and will let You know!

Comment: Great! I arrived to perfect solution and updated the header describing it. Thanks for Your reply! IEnumerable is really a must have!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the N+1 queries problem by having Linq2SQL eagerly load the referenced entites you need to construct your viewmodels. This way you can build one list of objects (and some referenced objects) and use it to construct everything. Have a look at this [blog post](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/02/linq-to-sql-and-asp-net-mvc-dataloadoptions-per-request/).

One word of warning though: This technique (setting LoadOptions for the Linq2SQL data context) can only be done once per data context. If you need to perform a second query with a different eager loading configuration, you must re-initalize your data context. I automated this with a simple wrapper class around my context.

Comment: I don't feel like this is the way to go, at least until i really need LoadOptions. I like to get 1 text field from Currency, not whole entity. 
The first fragment of code produces the SQL i want. I was looking for a way to reuse code AND make linq do miracles.

Comment: @insp - Returning a bigger entity really doesn't matter in the scheme of things.  @Adrians Grigore's technique really is the way to do things.

Comment: @insp: Unless you have huge amounts of data in your tables or execute the query extremely often, this solution should be fine. After all, premature optimization is the root of all evil (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Your advice is very good, however I am still writing code as in my last example. Prematurely optimized! :D In every LINQ query, I have to explicitly pass entity and each out-of-entity data to ViewModel constructor in params. The SQL is generated just the way i like it. The solution is still quite strong typed for code maintainance. When I upgrade ViewModel constructor, compiler shows parameter mismatch errors for every LINQ call needs to get updated ->much better than 1st example. So is it impossible to make function, expression or anything else that could do it automatically?